When interpreting results, should I report the coefficient for the quadratic term in a regression as-is or report the square root?
There's quite a few questions on related topics on CV (e.g. here) but I can't seem to find the answer to my exact question. It is something I thought I knew but I have questioned my knowledge lately and wanted to check.
Say I conduct a standard Gaussian regression with a linear and quadratic term for predictor X. We'll call the outcome Y.  The linear coefficient is 4 and the quadratic is -2. For simplicity I am leaving out intercepts, variance etc. I want to interpret the results in a sentence.
Is it correct to say "For every 1-unit increase in X there is an estimated 4-unit increase in Y, however the rate of increase in Y decreases by 2 units for every additional 1-unit increase in X."
...or should I be taking the square root of the quadratic coefficient when interpreting the quadratic (i.e. "a 1.41-unit decrease in the rate of increase in Y for every 1-unit increase in X")?

Neither. The quadratic term is not linear (...), so you can not make any statement of the form "for every $\delta x$ increase in X, there is an increase/decrease of $\delta y$ in Y". That only holds for linear relationships. With your coefficients (4 & -2) the curve is not even monotonic (it is a parabola). See here for this curve.
Start with x=0. If you add 1, this will add 2 to y (+4-2). Add 1 more, this will now subtract 2 (+4-6=-2). Add 1 again, and now you subtract 6 (+4-10) (see the graph).
The best way is to simply report the value of the coefficients, show the equation, and maybe a graph; a single sentence will not convery the relationship.

Thank you @jginestet. Can you explain how you arrived at the -6 and -10 (for x = 2 and x = 3 respectively I assume?)?

Would it be correct to say "the linear rate of increase in Y decreases by 2(x+1)^2 for every 1-unit increase in X"? Probably not a sentence you would ever write in a results section but is it correct?

Wrt the "linear rate"..., there is no linear rate, because the relationship is not linear, but quadratic. It increases for x<1, and decreases for x>1. If you absolutely insist such wording, the change from $y_x$ to $y_{x+1}$ is $y_x - y_{x+1}=(4x-2)$. And if you use this formula, you will get the changes in my answer. But I would advise to simply show the parabola; a) it will involve the intercept, you can show the curve on only the domain of x which makes sense in your case, and, as this parabola is pretty steep, a graph will express this much better (a graph is worth a 1000 words...)

Here is your regression equation.
$$
\hat y = \alpha + 4x - 2x^2
$$
You interpret the change by taking a derivative. When the regression does not include higher-order terms, this is equivalent to looking at the coefficient on the variable of interest. Since you do have a higher-order term in the quadratic, you have to calculate the derivative. I will use partial derivative notation to be general, even though there is only one independent variable in this particular case.
$$
\dfrac{\partial \hat y}{\partial x} = 4 - 4x
$$
Therefore, the change depends on the starting value of $x$, and you no longer have the simple notion of each unit of increase in $x$ leading to a particular change in the fitted value. For instance, if $x = 0$, then increasing $x$ means an increase in $\hat y$, as $\dfrac{\partial \hat y}{\partial x}=4$. However, if $x = 2$, then there is a decrease, as $\dfrac{\partial \hat y}{\partial x} = -4$.

Thank you @Dave, excellent answer. Forgive my rusty high school maths but doesn't your answer demonstrate that the value of Y at any given timepoint $n$ is comprised of a linear component - a constant of 4 - plus a quadratic component equal to $-4(x_n)$? Sure the additive slope will change direction but the slope is always made up of those two elements isn't it?

@llewmills I evaluated the derivatives at $x$-values.

Sorry yes, I should have written "the slope of the tangent to the curve at any given value of X is comprised of a linear component - a constant of 4 - plus a quadratic component equal to $-4(X)$". I accidentally brought timepoints into it (that is the predictor in my real world problem)

Yes, that is in my answer. @llewmills
